# Telling my code to generate all combinations of 00000 to 99999 but it doesn't?

Tags: python, combinations

my problem is that my script does not return a sufficient amount of combinations. My script looks like this.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

oneCombinations = list()
one = [i for i in range(0,10)]
    
for n in range(len(one) + 1):
    oneCombinations += list(combinations_with_replacement(one,5))

combs = list()

for t in oneCombinations:
    combs.append("".join(map(str,t)))
    
print(combs)
print(len(combs))
```

I wan't the script to return *all* combinations of 0 - 9, for example: 00000, 00001, 00002 and so forth. However this only returns a list of 22,022 combinations, which is not all of them. Since 10^5 is 100,000 should my list not contain 100,000 elements instead of 22,022? I have not fiddled with anything since I don't know where to start. I just can't see what I'm doing wrong, please help.

Comment: Can be easily done with `range(100000)` and a little formatting.

Comment: [11 * (14 choose 5)](https://www.google.com/search?q=11+*+%2814+choose+5%29) is indeed 22,022.

Comment: Kelly Bundy how did you come up with that, I don't get it.

Comment: The 11 is from your first loop, and the 14 choose 5 is for choosing 5 elements from 10 with replacement (14 being 10+5-1).

Comment: Ohh now it's clicking for me, thanks.

Comment: What's even the point of the first `for` loop? You will only get 11 duplicates of everything. And `combinations_with_replacement` doesn't seem the right thing for this at all.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the difference between [combination](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).  Combinations preserve the order of the elements from a given set::

```
combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC
```

As you see in the example above, combinations does not give you BA, CA or CB.

It appears that you are looking for a `product`, which gives you back a Cartesian product with all elements regardless of their order.

```
product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
```

something like::

```
map(''.join, product(map(str, range(10)), repeat=5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a cartesian product:

```py
from itertools import product
one = [i for i in range(0,10)]
tmp = [one for i in range(5)]
combs = [i for i in product(*tmp)]
```

Comment: Could you also show the normal way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by normal?

Comment: Well I'm assuming you only use those list comps because the OP did. Is that not the case? I mean `list(product(range(10), repeat=5))`.

Comment: Sure, I wanted to provide an answer that is as close to his attempt as possible. BTW I really like the approach by Klaus D :)

Comment: Thanks Kelly Bundy and Isolin, I'll be using this!

Comment: Yes, Klaus's way might be best here. Less general, but it's quite possible that the OP doesn't want something more general.

Comment: The question was why the code doesn't work, not how to make combinations.

Comment: Btw if they do want to go this route, it would be more efficient to stringify the digits *once*, *before* giving them to `product`: `list(map(''.join, product(map(str, range(10)), repeat=5)))`.